# How can I know that a projection is completed and need to publish an event for realtime subscription in CQRS?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, real-time, cqrs

I am attempting to learn and apply the CQRS design approach (pattern and architecture) to a new project but seem to be missing a key piece.

My client application executes a query and retrieves a list of documents (with joins) from the read model. The user selects an item and clicks a button to initiate some action. The action is performed by creating and sending the corresponding command object to the write model (where the command handler carries out the action, updates the data store, etc. by read model). At some point, however, I need to update the UI to reflect changes to the state of the application resulting from the action.

1. How does the UI know when it is time to refresh the original list?
2. The operation succeeds, data has changed and the UI should be updated to reflect these changes.
3. The operation fails, data has not changed but the user should be notified of the failure and potential corrective actions.

Without completion of projection, I can't fetch inserted/updated data and send back to UI by a real-time sockets. One solution, I can send the state of the same aggregate and aggregateId but in case of joins, how could I send full updates back (data with joins) to UI?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options for updating the UI.

If possible, it's easier if your API synchronously returns success/failure. If you get a failure, you can immediately report to the user, and you don't need to update the UI. If you get a success, you have some options.

1. Include in the success response some entity version information. Include in your read model some version information, and poll the query API until the version is new enough.
2. Include in the success response some entity version information. Have your query API allow you to specify that you want the data as-of at least that version (in a header, query parameter, or whatever). Either you can have the query API immediately return failure if it isn't yet up to date, or you can have it block until it is up to date (with a timeout) then return the up-to-date data.
3. Use some kind of client notification system such as web sockets to notify the client whenever the read model it is 'subscribed' to changes. Either the notification can include the information the client needs to update, or it can make another query.

On top of those options, you can also employ the technique of optimistic updates. In this case, after making the appropriate client side checks before issuing a command, you assume instantly that the command succeeded (if it's the kind of command that usually does succeed), update the UI immediately using client-side code. Then:

1. If the command comes back with failure, undo the client-side update (you could do this by re-fetching the read model, or using client-side code).
2. If the command succeeds, consider re-fetching the read model, if there's any likelihood that the client-side optimistic update isn't quite right. This should use one of the strategies listed above to ensure the command's effect is present in the read model.

This also works quite well with offline support - you queue commands up persistently in the client, and optimistically assume they succeed (perhaps with a UI indication that you are offline and data is stale) using client-side code to update the read model, until you can actually send the commands through to the server and re-fetch the server-generated read model.